# Page is not scrolling on div overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, scroll

I have a static page with 1 HTML and 1 CSS file.
When I test the page and type into the multiline textarea (last one on the page) until the page should overflow, it doesn't. The div with the id of 'centered' has a height of 'fit-content' and inspecting it shows that it does correcty fit the content and does overflow, but the browser doesn't show me a scrollbar. Also scrollBy doesn't work. And it isn't only one browser (Chrome desktop, android; Firefox desktop, android).

Here is index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Formr.io</title>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script defer>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                document.querySelectorAll(".long-answer").forEach((el) => {
                    let offset = el.offsetHeight - el.clientHeight;
                    el.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
                        event.target.style.height = 'auto';
                        event.target.style.height = event.target.scrollHeight + offset + 'px';
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="centered">

            <!-- Header -->

            <div class="question-container">
                <div class="form-header-color-bar"></div>
                <div class="form-header-title">Тест върху "Неразделни"</div>
                <div class="form-header-desc">Упражнителен тест върху "Неразделни"</div>
           </div>

            <br>

            <!-- Questions -->
            <div class="question-container">

                 <div class="question-title">Име и клас <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>

                 <br>

                 <div class="text-answer-container">
                    <input placeholder="Вашия отговор." class="short-answer" type="text" />
                 </div>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="question-container">

                <div class="question-title">Какво мислите за решението на Иво? Прекалил ли е? <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>

                <br>

                <div class="text-answer-container">
                   <input placeholder="Вашия отговор." class="short-answer" type="text" />
                </div>
           </div>

           <br>

           <div class="question-container">

                <div class="question-title">Теза: "Той ме прегърнал с клони, аз съм в него вейки свряла." <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>

                <br>

                <div class="text-answer-container">
                   <textarea placeholder="Вашия отговор." class="long-answer"></textarea>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is index.css:

```css
:root {
    --main-color: #d08aff;
    /*--background-color: #f8edff;*/
    --background-color: rgb(240, 235, 248);
}

body {
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    margin: 0px;
}

#centered {
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    left: 50%;
    width: 90%;
    height: fit-content;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.question-container {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e3e8;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
}

.question-container .form-header-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size: 24pt;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.question-container .form-header-desc {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10.5pt;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.question-container .form-header-color-bar {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 13px 13px 0px 0px;
}

.question-container .question-title {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.question-container .text-answer-container .short-answer {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    border: 1px solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 25px;
    min-width: 91px;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: calc(100% - 14px);
}

.question-container .text-answer-container .short-answer:focus {
    transition: 0.2s;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px var(--main-color);
}

.text-answer-container {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.question-container .text-answer-container .long-answer {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    border: 1px solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 7px;
    min-width: 91px;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: calc(100% - 14px);
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.question-container .text-answer-container .long-answer:focus {
    transition: 0.2s;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px var(--main-color);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the div is fixed it can't scroll.

Try this:

`#centered {
    position: absolute;
}`

instead of

`#centered {
    position: fixed;
}`